# Id of list versus str slices

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a list `a = [1,2,3]`, why is the following statement true

```
id(a[:]) == id(a[:]) # true
```

while the following one is false?

```
b = a[:]
id(b) == id(a[:]) # false
```

Also, if I instead use a string (in place of a list), then both statements are true. Why? What am I missing?

Comment: I think the question should be reopened. The related question does answer how list slicing and ids work, but it doesn't answer the main doubt Riccardo has which is why strings don't work the same way. The title might not reflect correctly his doubt, but that doesn't mean that the question has already been answered or that the related question is the answer to his doubt.

Comment: Just adding to question, `id(a[:]) == id(a[::-1]) == id(a[1:]) == id(a[:-1])` is `True` and `print(id(a[:]), id(a[::-1]), id(a[1:]), id(a[:-1]))` is giving `140453016802440, 140453016802440, 140453016802440, 140453016802440`

Comment: > Also, if I instead use a string (in place of a list), then both statements are true. -The same holds true for tuples as well (may be because these types are immutable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `id` is defined to be unique for an object *across its lifetime*. That is, two separate objects existing at the same time cannot have the same `id`. However, two separate objects *existing at different* time as well as objects *not required to be separate* may have the same `id`.

> ##### [id(object)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id)
>
> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.

---

Thus, one has to be mindful of two things when reasoning about `id`: When *must* the lifetime of objects overlap, and when *must* two objects be separate.

When the objects whose `id` we look at are created *only* for the `id`:

```py
>>> #  /  / first a[:]
>>> #  v  v       v    v second a[:]
>>> id(a[:]) == id(a[:])
True
```

then the object are not required to exist at the same time. Each `id(a[:])`  expression can create the slice, get its `id` *and then discard the slice* before the equality between the `id`s is ever checked. This means both slice can have the same `id` as they never exist at the same time.

In contrast, when a slice is assigned to a variable it has to exist *at least as long as the variable*. Thus, when we check the `id` of an object via a variable

```py
>>> b = a[:]           # < ------------- first a[:]
>>> id(b) == id(a[:])  # < second a[:]     |
False
>>> b                  # < ----------------/
…
```

its *lifetime overlaps* with that of the temporary slice. This means both slices must not have the same `id` as they never exist at the same time…

---

… *iff* slicing must create separate objects.

When comparing the behaviour of `list` and `str`, the key difference is that the latter does not have behaviour depending on its identity – roughly, this corresponds to *mutable* and *immutable* types.

When working with `list`s, identity is important because we can *mutate* a specific object. Even if two objects have the same initial value, mutation has a different effect:

```py
>>> a, b = [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]
>>> c = a         # a, b, c have same value
>>> c += [4]      # changing c has different effect on a and b
>>> a == b
False
```

When working with `str`, identity is irrelevant because we cannot mutate a specific object.  If two objects have the same initial value, immutability guarantees they will always have the same value:

```py
>>> a, b = "123", "123"
>>> c = a         # a, b, c have same value
>>> c += "4"       # changing c has *no* effect on a and b
>>> a == b
True
```

As a result, slicing a mutable `list` to a new `list` *must* always create a new object. Otherwise, mutating the slice would have unreliable behaviour.
In contrast, slicing an immutable `str` to a new `str` *may* create a new object. Even if it always provides the same object the behaviour is the same.

---

As a result of how `id` is defined – in respect to lifetime and separation – a Python implementation *must* use separate `id`s in specific cases but *may* use separate `id`s in all other cases.

In specific, a Python implementation is free to re-use `id`s if objects don't exist at the same time and is free to share `id`s if behaviour does not depend on identity.

Answer (score 2):

CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in memory.

Memory has limited room and you can treat them as a storage house with shelves, you might want to label every shelf with some digits or somewhat so you can find their precise position for convenience.

Every time you create new stuff they all must have a place to put it somewhere. you create a variable `a`, which means it's an object and it was labeled some address on it. you create a value `[1, 2, 3]`, it's another object and it still labeled some address on it.
Then you say
`a = 50;` you allocate 50 to a variable named `a`.

Under the hood, it says `a`'s address will reference to another address where `50` lives. (it's `pointer`)

A variable is an object. A pile of data is an object. Actually, a computer itself doesn't need a variable called `a`. It already has the address of [1, 2, 3], it knows where it is in memory. The reason we need a variable called `a` is that we human beings need a name to represent this pile of data instead of using an address.

The example in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a ;
    printf("The address of a is %p\n\n", &a);

    a = 55;
    printf("The address of a is %p\n", &a);
    printf("The address of 55's pointer is %p\n\n", 55);

    a = 30;
    printf("The address of a is %p\n", &a);
    printf("The address of 30's pointer is %p\n\n", 30);    
}
```

```
// The address of a is 0x7fffb44b83dc

// The address of a is 0x7fffb44b83dc
// The address of 55's pointer is 0x37

// The address of a is 0x7fffb44b83dc
// The address of 30's pointer is 0x1e
```

you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51658307/what-information-do-c-variables-contain-under-the-hood) for further reading

Back to here, whatever value we create after there existing `a = [1, 2, 3]`

`a[0], a[1], a[:2], a[:], a[::-1]`, etc. will occupy new space memory and has their own address individually, They are brand new objects since the script interpreted.

The `a`'s address won't change whether you assign other value to it, it only leads to point to another value's address.

Comment: `printf("The address of 55 is %p\n\n", 55);` This doesn't print the address of 55 though

Comment: This does not answer my questions

Comment: _will occupy new space memory and has their own address individually_ but it doesn't look like so. `id` is returning same memory location as reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69281502/id-of-list-versus-str-slices#comment122454691_69281502).

Comment: @RaviJoshi, I think this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753364/why-is-the-id-of-a-python-class-not-unique-when-called-quickly

Comment: This seems to sublty confuse how C and Python (and some other languages) work. Most prominently, in Python variables aren't objects and assignments like ``a = 50`` *don't* allocate the value to the variable. By extension `id(a)` is the address of the object *referred to* by the variable, not the variable itself; it's not comparable to getting the address of a variable in C.

Answer (score -1):

just print the ids

```
a = [1,2,3]
print(id(a), id(a[:])) # "a" has id#001 and its copy id#002

b = a[:] # here "b" inherits id#002 and the first copy of "a" dies
print(id(b), id(a[:])) # here "b" is still id#002, "a" is a new copy with id#003
```